# How to run tests and then application on save?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

In sbt, to run tests on save, I do "~test". When I want to run application on save, I do "~run". What do I do when I want to first run the tests and then run the application on save?

I tried "~ all test run", but it gave me an error

```
> ~ all test run
[error] Cannot mix input tasks with plain tasks/settings.  Input task(s):
[error]         ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/home/johnreed/sbtProjects/activatorProjects/hello-scala/,hello-scala)),Select(ConfigKey(compile)),Global,Global),run)
[error]  Task(s)/setting(s):
[error]         ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/home/johnreed/sbtProjects/activatorProjects/hello-scala/,hello-scala)),Select(ConfigKey(test)),Global,Global),test)
[error] 
[error] all test run
```

p.s. I want to be able to automatically and continuously run tests and run the Play application from IntelliJ Community Edition by clicking the green "Run" button.

[image: run]

Comment: You can hook the test task using [play's dev mode hooks](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTCookbook#Hooking-into-Plays-dev-mode).

Answer (score 1):

In sbt shell, execute `~ ; test ; run`.

```
[scala-morning-warmup]> help ;
; command1 ; command2 ...

    Runs the specified commands.
```

If you're on command line, you have to make sure that `~ ; test ; run` is considered a single input parameter to sbt so double-quote it.

```
sbt "~ ; test ; run"
```